# Is the simperium framework available for OSX too?

Tags: simperium

I'm getting a warning when building with the simperium.framework in OSX.

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Volumes/Jose/Desktop/simperium/Simperium.framework/Simperium, missing
>   required architecture x86_64 in file
>   /Volumes/Jose/Desktop/simperium/Simperium.framework/Simperium (3
>   slices)

Did I downloaded the wrong framework, or is simperium not available yet for OSX ?

Answer (score 0):

That's the framework for iOS. You're correct that a binary download for the OSX framework isn't currently linked. You can [build the framework from source](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios), or I'll also upload a binary OSX framework this weekend, and then update this answer.

Comment: looking forward to it.. Thank you.